# Declare Chart title font name

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm formatting a chart and these statements all work fine, except for the last one. What is the correct form?

```
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "History of IMS Transaction 'SPTVMS02'"
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 20
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Bold = False
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Color = RGB(110, 10, 155)

***ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Name = 'Calibri'***
```

Comment: You should look into the `With` statement. It will make your life easier (and improve performance somewhat).

Answer (score 5):

You should have double quotes around the font name instead of single quotes:

```
 ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Name = "Calibri"
```

Comment: @user1097112 - You're welcome! (And I'd very much appreciate it if -- when you get the chance -- you'd mark my answer as the correct one.)

Comment: @user1097112 - Next to my answer you'll see an outline of a check mark. Click on it, the check mark will turn green, and Stack Overflow will record my answer as the correct one. Thanks!